# MySQL Date calculation

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have exhausted my searches looking for a solution to this MySQL date calculation. My client wants to know how many deals were done in the past week, month and year.

It is a SQL based script (but in MySQL language) I am busy with, so don't bother with the Select, From etc.
The datetime_created field (in the script) is already in UnixTime, while the timestamp(now) is used to calculate current date minus 7 days.
As the formula result can be negative as well, I only require the result between 0.01 and 7.

My formula for the past week is listed below. Any ideas?

```
(registrations.datetime_created -unix_timestamp(now())-604800)/86400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Where clause was not accepted at all, and I had to change some logic.Thanks all, but the final script was a concoction from everyone, and is as follows:

```
registrations.datetime_created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 WEEK))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using UNIX_TIMESTAMP / ADDDATE() / between?

**Edit** slight expansion to clarify

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM registrations
WHERE registrations.datetime_created
    -- will go back to now() - a month INCLUDING time.  -1 WEEK/MONTH/YEAR etc all works here
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ADDDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 WEEK)) 
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())                                   
    -- will start at now() including time
```

By specifying the start and end timestamp within the WHERE criteria, MySQL is able to use an index on the `datetime_created` field (if one is present) to do this very efficiently.  If, instead, you have a WHERE `registrations.datetime_created*1235/12515` (an operation on the field) within the WHERE then you will see it returning slower as MySQL will need to scan the whole table to determine which rows to return.

Comment: This selects records between today and 7 days ahead, not the past week

Comment: Doesn't work I'm afraid the error message I have received wont help at all. It appears to be the DateAdd function that is the issue.

Comment: Changed it a bit, as the Date(registration.datetime_created) is not working. Keep in mind that this is a timestamp field. 
Still not working, although all functions independently do wor.

Comment: The From_UnixTime formula creates a date AND time, while your formulae only works with dates. Perhaps part of the issue, or even the only issue?

Comment: The DATE() around it is intended to strip the time, had assumed that was desired.  If not then just remove all DATE() references and it will deal with timestamps instead.  The idea here is, instead of calculating for each row, you calculate the max and min date (or datetime/timestamps) that you are looking for and then select those rows.  This simple change makes the query far more efficient as if you have to calculate the formula on every row then it will need to scan the table instead of relying on an index.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't tested, but I think it will do what you want:

```
SELECT
    q1.dealsInLastWeek,
    q2.dealsInLastMonth,
    q3.dealsInLastYear
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS dealsInLastWeek FROM registrations WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime_created) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 WEEK)) q1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS dealsInLastMonth FROM registrations WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime_created) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) q2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS dealsInLastYear FROM registrations WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime_created) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR)) q3
```

Comment: Hi, Date_Add is not accepted as formula. I will have to look into this a bit more, as  have tried Interval, but couldnt get it to work.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Comment: Happy that you assisted as well!

Answer (score 0):

Test with INTERVAL

```
SELECT (unix_timestamp(now()-INTERVAL '7' DAY)),(unix_timestamp(now()-INTERVAL '1' MONTH)),(unix_timestamp(now()-INTERVAL '1' YEAR));

WHERE registrations.datetime_created>(unix_timestamp(now()-INTERVAL '7' DAY))
```